# Dummy Node in Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to develop a way in which I can solve Linked list problems without having to care about the head node in any special way i.e. In linked list problems we usually deal with the head pointer separately before we start with the next nodes.

I found a way: Use a dummy node so that the actual linked list begins from dummy.next.

I am trying to solve a [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) using that way:

```
 struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 };

 ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {

        ListNode dummy = ListNode(0);
        ListNode * temp = dummy.next;
        int carry =0;

        while(l1!=NULL && l2!=NULL)
        {
            int x = (l1->val + l2->val + carry)%10;
            temp = new ListNode(x);
            carry = (l1->val + l2->val + carry)/10;
            temp = temp->next;
            l1 = l1->next;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }

        ListNode * p = (l1!=NULL)?l1:l2;

        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            int x = (p->val+carry)%10;
            temp = new ListNode(x);
            carry = (p->val+carry)/10;
            temp = temp->next;
            p = p->next;
        }

        if(carry==1) temp = new ListNode(1);

        return dummy.next;

    }

int main()
{
    ListNode * l1 = new ListNode(0), *l2 = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode * l3 = addTwoNumbers(l1,l2);

}
```

In this problem I tried not to initialize a head node separately. Obviously, the code does not do what I want it to, but I tried this way and now, I can't figure out how to proceed in this approach.

That is, Use the dummy node so that there is no need to separately handle the head node of the newly created linked list.

Any way to use this approach to solve the problem ?

Comment: Use `std::list` and kiss linked list problems goodbye.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thx but can't do that. Have to solve it this :).

Comment: Using a dummy node does not seem to be a reasonable idea. It just pushes the problems you're trying to solve further. Whatever this problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this approach

```
ListNode * addTwoLists(ListNode * first, ListNode * second) {
    ListNode * res = NULL, * temp, * prev = NULL;
    int carry = 0, sum;
    while (first != NULL || second != NULL) {
        sum = carry + (first ? first->val : 0) + (second ? second->val : 0);
        carry = (sum >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
        sum %= 10;
        temp = new ListNode(sum);
        if (res == NULL)
            res = temp;
        else
            prev->next = temp;
        prev = temp;
        if (first) first = first->next;
        if (second) second = second->next;
    }
    if (carry > 0)
        temp->next = new ListNode(carry);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I figured out after seeing your approach and  my code now works with just one line of change. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: @Shreevardhan This code would just seg fault.  I think you need the `else` that I have added here: `if (res == NULL)
            res = temp;
        else prev->next = temp;`

Comment: @adrian008 I'd be amazed to see that one line change.  I don't think the change needs to be fundamental, but still much more than one line.

Comment: @JSF Well its just one line really, *temp = & dummy and then, I could use temp->next in the 2 places where I create nodes (instead of temp). So, technically its three lines of change :) , which is still less than much more :).

Comment: @JSF You are right, missed the `else`. Fixed the typo. Thanks.

Comment: The original problem statement said 'without having to care about the head node in any special way'.  That if/else is exactly the (excessive) caring about the head node that one would want to avoid.

Comment: @adrian008, you had `temp = new ListNode` in three places.  Did you miss one in correcting your code?  All three need to be changed, plus the "one" line you "really" changed, making a minimum of 4 by my count.

Comment: @JSF Okay you win :). I can only say thanks for your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With or without a dummy node, a key part of building a new list is staying one node behind where you logically are.  I prefer to do so without a dummy node, so the pointer used for current position is `ListNode** temp` and you allocate new nodes with `(*temp)=new ListNode(x)` and advance to the next (predecessor) position with `temp=&(*temp)->next`.  If you prefer to use a dummy node, you use `ListNode* temp=&dummy;` and allocate new nodes with `temp->next=new ListNode(x)` and advance with `temp=temp->next` only after your logical position is one beyond that.

Edit based on your comment.  If you want to avoid the syntax (not reality) of the double pointer:

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {

        ListNode dummy = ListNode(0);
        ListNode * temp = &dummy;
        int carry =0;

        while(l1!=NULL || l2!=NULL)
        {
            if (l1!=NULL)
            {
                 carry += l1->val;
                 l1 = l1->next;
            }
            if (l2!=NULL)
            {
                 carry += l2->val;
                 l2 = l2->next;
            }

            temp = temp->next = new ListNode(carry%10);
            carry /= 10;
        }

        if(carry==1) temp->next = new ListNode(1);

        return dummy.next;

    }
```

Comment: I can do it that way, I don't want to use (*temp), I don't want to use double pointer.

Comment: You MUST use a double pointer whether you want to on not.  A dummy node can be used to syntactically mask the fact that you are using a double pointer.  That is fine if the SYNTAX of a double pointer bothers you.  But the reality of the double pointer must still be there, even if syntactically hidden.  Your attempt to use a dummy node to drop the reality (rather than just syntax) of the double pointer simply doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks and I used saw the approach of Sreevardhan's answer, I didn't run it. what he did is he used three pointers to keep track, with dummy node I neeed just one temp pointer to achieve what he did. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

These parts are your problem:

```
        temp = new ListNode(x);
        carry = (l1->val + l2->val + carry)/10;
        temp = temp->next;
```

You create a new ListNode, then with `temp = temp->next` just *forget* it. `temp->next` is `NULL` at that time and you lose any ability to access your previously created ListNode, let alone modify it's `next` pointer.

Start over. This is broken by design.

Comment: No, I mean I am updating temp in each iteration, temp temp->next updates it doesn't, so where is it forgetting ?

Comment: No you don't, you assign `temp` the value of `temp->next`, thus just dropping our only pointer to your newly created ListNode.

Comment: Yes, I had fixed it actually. Thanks.

Comment: The basic patern `temp=new ListNode(x); ... temp=temp-next;` is broken as Felix indicated.  But 'start over' is a bit much.  As you can see in my answer, you can use `temp=temp->next=new ListNode(x)` as your basic pattern combined with starting at `&dummy` instead of `dummy->next`.  The rest of the differences between my version and the original are just cleanup to reduce duplicated work, rather than fundamental correction.